# Unicorn not completely restoring serialized content from disk on sync

Tags: sxa, unicorn, serialization

For interim development purposes, I've serialized my entire SXA tenant folder content tree, related templates, media library, etc. I haven't specified to exclude children in the config; so I expect the roots and all children to be serialized.

The problem is when I check into source control and have a developer check out and sync my Sitecore items, they're only partially restored. When I check the directory the serialized content is checked out and synced from, all the missing content from his Sitecore instance seems to be in the directory/file tree structure, it's just not being restored to Sitecore on sync. He has the same Unicorn configuration that I do and all the same serialized files. Yet, when he restores, only part of the content seems to be installed, even though it would seem to be included in the config.

We're both using Sitecore 9.1 with SXA 1.8; same configuration.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here to fix this?

```
    <configuration
      name="Site.Serialization"
      description="Root items"
      extends="Site.Serialization.Base">
      <predicate>

        <!--Core database serialized updates-->
        <include name="core.templates.Feature" database="core" path="/sitecore/templates/Feature" >
        </include>
        <include name="core.templates.Foundation" database="core" path="/sitecore/templates/Foundation">
        </include>
        <include name="core.templates.Project" database="core" path="/sitecore/templates/Project">
        </include>

        <include name="master.globaltoolkit.themes" database="master" path="/sitecore/media library/Themes/Site">
        </include>
        <include name="master.globaltoolkit.medialibrary" database="master" path="/sitecore/media library/Project">
        </include>
        <include name="master.Templates.Feature" database="master" path="/sitecore/templates/Feature">
        </include>
        <include name="master.Templates.Foundation" database="master" path="/sitecore/templates/Foundation">
        </include>
        <include name="master.Templates.Project" database="master" path="/sitecore/templates/Project">
        </include>
        <include name="master.Settings.Feature" database="master" path="/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature">
        </include>
        <include name="master.Settings.Foundation" database="master" path="/sitecore/system/Settings/Foundation">
        </include>
        <include name="master.Settings.Project" database="master" path="/sitecore/system/Settings/Project">
        </include>
        <include name="master.globaltoolkit.content" database="master" path="/sitecore/content/TenantFolder">
        </include>


      </predicate>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: There was a known issue around this, specifically with SXA tenants and SXA content. It was fixed in Unicorn 4.0.8 / Rainbow 2.0.6. Make sure you're on that version and the problem should go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. The file paths to the serialized files were too long, and Unicorn was skipping them on sync. Shortening the checkout directory resolved the issue.